# Replace MR16 downlight bathroom help please!

Tags: lighting, bathroom

[image]
Hi everyone

Please help. I cannot find a way to replace the MR16/GU5.3 bulb in my bathroom downlight.  There are no tabs to release the bulb.  I have pulled down the entire assembly but the bulb cannot be released from behind as it is restricted by a ring built in to the assembly. So I cannot seem to release it while it is in position and I cannot release it by removing the assembly from the ceiling.  I dont think it is a sucker type either.  Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Normally you need to pull down on the silver ring to get access they are commonly spring loaded and even tension on either side downward will pull it about 3” down then the lamp has a spring clip holding it in place. Some have fancy levers that lock the power socket and hold the lamp in place when it is pushed back up. I would be trying to find an LED replacement because these lamps have a very short life for the cost.

Comment: I second the LED replacement. A couple of can-less LED fixtures will be very low maintenance.

Comment: Many thanks - I got it now!!

Answer (score 0):

MR16s just pull.*

The fun part is trying to get behind them to get a grip.
Try a flexible steel tape measure, the self-retracting type you get from the DIY store for $£€ 1.

[image]

Loop it around the back & pull.
I've never owned any with retaining clips more sophisticated than a kind of figure-8 spring, which this method easily overcomes.

As already mentioned replace with LED.

*Note: GU10s push & twist so be certain it's an MR16 before trying to rive it out of its socket ;)